# How to display username on home page only after login?

Tags: javascript, php, html

//header.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
$_SESSION['displayname']="notset";
else
$_SESSION['loggedin']=0;
?>
```

//index.php

```
<?php
require "header.php";
if($_SESSION['loggedin']==1) //ignores the if statement
{
echo "Welcome".$_SESSION['displayname']."!";
echo "<button id='logout_button'>
<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>
}
else
{
echo '<a id="display_name" href="login.html">Login/ Signup</a>';
}
?>
```

//verify.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connect.php";
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

$check=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM member_list WHERE       username='$uname'");
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);

if ($numrows == 1)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($check);
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];

    if( $uname == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword )
    { 
        $_SESSION['loggedin']=1;
        $_SESSION['displayname'] = $uname;
        header("location:index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $msg="Invalid Password !!";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg'); 
        window.location.replace('loggedin.html')</script>";
    }
}
else
{
    $msg="Invalid Username !!";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg'); 
    window.location.replace('index.html')</script>";

}
?>
```

This is my code. There is no error. But when I login it does not display the username. It ignores the if statement on index.php and goes straight to the else statement.

Comment: You are missing `session_start();` on top at your `index.php` file.

Comment: Place this at the top of the index file `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` . Does it show any error now?

Comment: `echo "<button id='logout_button'>
<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>"  ` is not closing in your index.php

Comment: why you can re initialize `$_SESSION['displayname'] = 'notset'` in header page

Comment: @icecub
He does not need to put `session_start()` in index.php because he is already including header.php, which in turn does have `session_start()`.

Comment: `It ignores the if statement […] and goes straight to the else statement` that's how I expect the _if_ compound statement to work when the controlling _condition_ is not met -?

Comment: but when i login the value of $_SESSION['loggedin'] is changed to '1'. So why does it still go for the else statement?

Answer (score 0):

try this to debug your apps

index.php

```
<?php
//start header.php
ob_start();
session_start();
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) ? $_SESSION['loggedin'] : 0;
if($_SESSION['loggedin']==1)
    $_SESSION['displayname']="admin";
else
    $_SESSION['displayname']="guest";
//end header.php

if($_SESSION['loggedin']==1)
{
    echo $_SESSION['displayname'];
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
else
{
    echo $_SESSION['displayname'];
    echo "<a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$_SESSION['loggedin']=1;
echo "try login....";
sleep(1);
header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$_SESSION=NULL;
session_destroy();
echo "try logout....";
sleep(1);
header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
?>
```

let me know this script work or not

Comment: With this code the $_SESSION['loggedin'] in index.php becomes unidentified. $_SESSION['loggedin'] must be initialized first. When we visit index.php for the first time $_SESSION['loggedin'] is not initialized.